# what does the down arrow mean in intellisense in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

[image]

As you can see the little downward arrow in the red rectangle.
Does it mean this method has been obsoleted?

If it is, then what is the update-to-date replacement?

For example, I want to use a textbox on my Razor page, but it seems that all input components have been marked as obsoleted.

Confused~~~~~

It would be better if someone could provide a link which states all these glyphicos on a Microsoft website.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That means the method is an extension method.

You can check the [icon meanings here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe.aspx).